# Is it possible to import *.vue files in a folder?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vue-component

I hate repeating things in code. For now I am importing vue files like this in my main.js.

```
import Default     from '../../src/components/default.vue';
import Home        from '../../src/components/home.vue';
import hakkinda    from '../../src/components/hakkinda.vue';
import projeler    from '../../src/components/projeler.vue';
import servisler   from '../../src/components/servisler.vue';
import yetenekler  from '../../src/components/yetenekler.vue';
import yetenek     from '../../src/components/yetenek.vue';
import referanslar from '../../src/components/referanslar.vue';
import iletisim    from '../../src/components/iletisim.vue';
```

Is there a way to do same thing with less lines? Could be great if I can assign variable name from filename. Can PHP help about it? But then how to compile main.js? I did not figured out.

Comment: are you using Webpack ?

Comment: Nope, I am using vue-cli to compile. But I think I can assign a config file when compiling. Is it help?

Comment: Vue CLI use the webpack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use this script in a file named "index.js" to "export default all exported default in every file in the current folder" sort of thing:

```
const files = require.context('.', false, /\.js$/)
const modules = {}
files.keys().forEach((key) => {
  if (key === './index.js') return
  modules[ key.replace(/(\.\/|\.js)/g, '') ] = files(key).default
})
export default modules
```

Then you can import the whole directory by importing it's name, just like this:

```
import folder from '../path/to/folder'
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I had to replace few things to get it to work. `files(key).default` with `files(key)`. `require.context('.', false, /\.js$/)` with `require.context('.', false, /\.vue$/)`. `key.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, '')` with `key.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, '')`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Potray and Fosuze's working answers for easy reference:

```
const files = require.context('.', false, /\.vue$/)
const modules = {}
files.keys().forEach((key) => {
     if (key === './index.js') return
     modules[key.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, '')] = files(key)
})
export default modules
```

Answer (score 2):

[See the medium post I created](https://medium.com/@mo.belhaj/dynamically-render-a-component-from-an-imported-folder-vue-js-87a5a0ae1b07)

I'll explain it in an in-depth / easy way there.

For a quick answer here.

- Create a folder (*let's say **colors** folders for example*)
- create and or add your Vue files inside of that folder *(sample **red.vue, blue.vue, green.vue**)*
- add to that folder *(**colors** folder)*  an **index.js** containing *(This is based on oprogfrogo's answer.).*

```
const files = require.context('.', false, /\.vue$/)
const modules = {}
files.keys().forEach((key) => {
     if (key === './index.js') return
     modules[key.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, '')] = files(key)
})
export default modules
```

your directory looks like for example

- colors/
- colors/red.vue
- colors/blue.vue
- colors/green.vue
- colors/index.js

then in any component, you can

```
 import colors from "./colors/index" //location of the folder
 console.log(colors);
 let yourComponent = colors['blue'].default // wil get you that component
```

where `['is the file name']`

then in your template, you can

```
<component v-bind:is="yourComponent"></component>
```

Comment: Please remember to disclose that the blog post you are linking to is your own ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)). Failure to disclose affiliations can result in your posts being treated as spam, potentially resulting in a lost of reputation or a suspension.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I now disclosed that it's made by me. Someone has to give an answer to this question. Thanks for your input.