# Image Folder Within dist Not Added To Heroku Website

Tags: heroku, vuejs3, vueperslides

I've deployed my website using Heroku. I am also using [Vueper Slides](https://antoniandre.github.io/vueper-slides/) which needs a variable, which is an array, containing the path to the image. On the live website I noticed that it does not contain the `images` folder contained in my `dist` folder. What can I do to fix this?

Javascript array variable:
[image: Javascript array variable]

dist directory:

[image: dist directory]

Heroku source files:

[image: Heroku source files]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a definite answer, but can help.

I noticed you are using the `public` folder where you keep your images.
you may want to double check that the path is correct because it should just load stuff within the `public` folder.

However, I don't understand why it doesn't load in the `images` folder from dist.

Comment: I'm embarrassed, the path had a typo. It works now, but is there a way to import the `images` folder?

Comment: @Stove Games Games this may be useful but I would not advise doing this for images since it's a lot of manual labor and the `public` folder works just fine if not better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199872/is-it-possible-to-import-vue-files-in-a-folder