# Dynamically importing dynamic components in Vue 2.7

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

Please note that this is a legacy Vue `2.7` codebase running on webpack, so any Vue 3 or Vite related solutions unfortunately won't work for me.

I'm reworking an old navbar that is dynamically generated based on a JSON we receive from one of our endpoints. One of the things that I'm reworking is refactoring the icons from the old FontAwesome icons we were using to our homecooked icon library, where each icon is now a separate Vue component.

My issue is that this navbar will, at minimum, have 16 different items in it with 16 different icons. It's also possible for the user to customize their navbar and add/remove these 16 icons to their liking, though the icons will be limited to what our icon library offers.

So the solution here is to use the dynamic `<component>` tag, like so:

```js
<component :is="item.icon" />
```

The problem being that I have to import these icons and define them within `components: {}`.

```js
import { MyIcon } from "icons";

export default {
  components: { MyIcon }
}
```

You can see where the issue comes in, I have no idea which icons might be present in the navbar ahead of time. Importing the entire icon library is also out of the question, since we have somewhere around 800 icons and not all of them are currently used in the actual application, plus they're lazy-loaded and tree-shaken and all that good stuff.

Is there a way for me to iterate over the `items` array, and to dynamically import each icon that is defined from in there? The Object we receive from our endpoint looks something like this:

```js
{
  icon: 'my-icon',
},
{
  icon: 'my-other-icon,
}
```

I think the solution here is using a dynamic `import()` in the `mounted` of the component (or some other hook) using the nav items, but I couldn't figure out a way of doing that without also importing every single icon (which is what I'm trying to avoid in the first place).

I've also tried a variant like below, but it doesn't really work with the way our Icon library is setup and leads to a number of hard to decipher webpack errors.

```
const icon = import('myIconLibrary/${icon.type}/${icon.name}.vue')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199872/is-it-possible-to-import-vue-files-in-a-folder . The result of import() is a promise, this needs to be additionally handled. It's unknown how your webpack is configured so nothing can be suggested at this point to improve this

Answer (score 3):

you can try doing a computed that dynamically import the need icon :

```
  computed: {
    iconComponent() {
      return () => import(`myIconLibrary/${this.icon.type}/${this.icon.name}.vue`);
    }
  }
```